# Класс в качестве параметра другого класса

Tags: java

Здесь, как я понимаю, три класса взаимодействуют друг с другом опираясь на четвёртый(class B).

```
public abstract class A {

public B bb;

// constructor
public A(B beb) {
    bb = beb;        
}
}

public class B {
  /*Класс
  с переменными
  и методами*/
}

public class C extends A {

//constructor
public C(B beb){
    super(beb);
}
}
```

*Ниже непонятно когда класс С вызывается с ссылкой на класс B в качестве параметра.*

```
public class D{

public B bb;
public C cc;

public void init(){
cc = new C(bb);  
}
```

**А что именно происходит во всём коде?**

P.S. работать программа начинает с метода init()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

тут:

```
cc = new C(bb);
```

создается экземпляр класса `C`, при это в конструктор передается как параметр ссылка на экземлпяр `B` (bb).

далее конструктор `C`:

```
public C(B beb){
    super(beb);
}
```

принимает как аргумент экземпляряр и вызывает родительский конструктор передавая туда `B`

В родительском конструкторе

```
public A(B beb) {
    bb = beb;        
}
```

`beb` складывается в переменную `bb`

---

Вопрос невнятный и не похож вообще на вопрос. Поэтому и ответ в таком же стиле.

Comment: А когда ссылка на экземпляр передаётся как параметр - передаются все переменные и методы?

Comment: @YOLOSTYLE ну да... но обратиться все равно можно только к публичным.